# Global variables with apollo and express

Tags: node.js, apollo-server

index.js

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
import express from 'express'

global.myTest = true
```

/models/user.js

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
console.log('test:' + global.myTest)
```

Anyone knows how to set global variables with Apollo Server Express ? The example above returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Due to es6 `import` module hoisted. All the dependent Modules will be loaded before running any code. You need to make sure to access the `global.myTest` after it has been defined and assigned. You can use nodejs `require` keyword to require your user model after assign value to `global.myTest`.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';

global.myTest = true;

require('./models/user');
```

`./models/user.js`:

```js
console.log('test:' + global.myTest);
```

The output of the console:

```sh
$ npx ts-node ./index.js
test:true
```